# py.test : do something just after a test

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

For my tests, I build temporary files that I would like to remove whatever the result of the test is (failure or test passed).

Is there a way to "tell" to `py.test` to do something just after it finishes to test my Python file ?

Comment: http://pytest.org/latest/xunit_setup.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this. It seems that [this link](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code) is more revenant. If an administrator wants to close my question, he vena do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a canvas found in the official documentation.

```
from pytest import fixture

@fixture(scope="module")
def or_datas(request):
    # Something done before a test.

    def fin():
        # Here, just do something after the test.
        ...

    request.addfinalizer(fin)


# How to use it ?

def test_something(or_datas):
    # Note the argument corresponding the function decorated
    # by fixture.
    ...
```